# Topological group locally homeomorphic to the Hilbert cube

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Does there exist a topological group which is locally homeomorphic to the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$?

Let me note that Hilbert cube has the fixed point property and thus it is not homeomorphic to a topological group. Also, as a consequence of a recent paper by Arhangelskii and van Mill (Covering Tychonoff cubes by topological groups, Topology and its applications 2020), there is no topological group which is locally homeomorphic to $[0,1]^{\kappa}$, where $\kappa\geq\omega_1$.

A related question could be: is there a topological group structure on $\mathbb S^1\times [0,1]^{\mathbb N}$?

Comment: is it locally homogeneous (i.e., is it true that any points $x,y$ have neighborhoods $V,W$ with a homeomorphism $V\to W$ mapping $x$ to $y$)? the question is the same for the $[0,1]^\omega$ and $[0,1]^\omega\times S^1$, since they're locally homeomorphic.

Comment: Hilbert cube is known to be homogeneous i.e. for every $x,y\in Q=[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ there is a homeomorphism $h:Q\to Q$ such that $h(x)=y$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is no.

Since the Hilbert cube is compact and locally contractible, such a group would be a locally contractible locally compact group. And every locally contractible locally compact group is Lie (i.e., locally homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^d$ for some integer $d<\infty$).

---

For a reference

> Szenthe, J.
> On the topological characterization of transitive Lie group actions.
> Acta Sci. Math. (Szeged) 36 (1974), 323–344. [Link](http://acta.bibl.u-szeged.hu/14497/1/math_036_fasc_003_004_323-344.pdf)

Theorem 3 there: *Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $H$ a closed subgroup such
that the coset space $G/H$ is locally contractible. Then $G/H$ is a free* [=disjoint] *union of manifolds
which are coset spaces of Lie groups.*

(I've seen it attributed, when $H=1$ to earlier work of Gleason and Montgomery-Zippin without precise reference.)

*Edit:* Taras Banakh mentions in a comment that the Szenthe's proof has a gap, and that this gap is fixed independently in:

> S. Antonyan, T. Dobrowolski, Locally contractible coset spaces.
> Forum Math. 27 (2015), no. 4, 2157–2175. [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1515/forum-2013-0033)

> K. Hofmann, L. Kramer. Transitive actions of locally compact groups on locally contractible spaces. J. Reine Angew. Math. 702 (2015), 227–243 (+ erratum 245–246). [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1515/crelle-2013-0036) [ArXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5114)

Also, user Tyrone mentions that a negative solution to the OP's question (not addressing general locally contractible locally compact groups) is the statement of Theorem 3.1 in

> A. Fathi, Y. Visetti. Deformation of open embeddings of Q-manifolds. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 224 (1976), no. 2, 427–435 (1977). [link at AMS site](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1976-224-02/S0002-9947-1976-0420668-4/S0002-9947-1976-0420668-4.pdf) [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.2307/1997487)

Comment: The same argument applies to the $[0,1]^\kappa$ case of course (the result in the paper cited in the question is much stronger than just $[0,1]^\kappa$ does not support a topological group structure though)

Comment: Could you quote a theorem? Every statement I have seen includes the assumption of finite-dimensionality. (As I understand it, the original question is more delicate and was an open problem for several years in the 70's. A solution appears in $\S$3 of the 1976 paper [Deformation of Open Embeddings of Q-Manifolds](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1976-224-02/S0002-9947-1976-0420668-4/S0002-9947-1976-0420668-4.pdf) by Fathi and Viseti.)

Comment: @Tyrone I had quoted a theorem of the Szenthe 1974 paper. (However I'm not sure it appears in Gleason / Montgomery-Zippin, so I've modified the reference. I have also added the link to the Szenthe paper.)

Comment: As far as I know there was some problem with the proof of the result of Szenthe. So, this result of Szenthe was recently reproved by Hoffmann and Kramer in (https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crelle-2013-0036/html). But their proof also contained a gap, which was later fixed in (https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crelle-2013-5001/html). Also the same result of Szenthe has been reproved by Antonyan and Dobrowolski in (https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/forum-2013-0033/html).